# How do you get google to crawl a meteor js website?

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, google-search-console, google-crawlers

I have tried quite a few things including the spiderable and ms-seo packages, but nothing seems to work. I tried setting the fragment meta tag but google webmaster tools still seems to fetch a document which is missing the header tags (inserted using ms-seo) and an empty body. I'm sure there is a concrete solution out there since I can't be the only one trying to get Google to crawl my meteor website. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/meteor-and-seo

It should render the html server side and show that to google it's search engine.

Google web admin might not show the page though, in the comments in above url it's also noted as an issue.

Comment: So I tried this one, but when like I take a look at what Google fetches in the webmaster tools, it shows me an empty body and none of the meta tags I set using ms-seo. So I am assuming Google isnt indexing these correctly either

Comment: Router.route('/', function () {
    SEO.set({
      title: 'new title',
      meta: {
        'description': "new description",
        'author':"Sandeep"
      }
    });
  } 
});

Comment: It's a common issue but it doesn't mean that it doesn't index the site properly: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/meteor-talk/flzi_YIvPmY